# I make tags to articles, but they do not appear on the page

Tags: python, html, django

I have a function that processes the request by tags and sorts articles with similar tags and displays them in a template. But for some reason, they simply do not appear on the page. I fill them in the model using  TaggableManager

I put tags on the page in this way

```
   <p class="post-meta">
        TAGS:
            <a href=""> {{ tag.name }}</a> |
    </p>
```

P.S tags should appear on the article and when I click on them, the request should be processed and execute the post _search function and sent to the page with articles with tags I have selected.

models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    view = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    datesArticle = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-datesArticle']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def ArticleDetailView(request, pk):

      Articles.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(view=F('view') + 1)
      Articles.objects.all()
      article_details = Articles.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()

      if request.method == 'POST':
          comment_form = Comments(request.POST)
          comment_form.save()
      else:
          comment_form = Comments()

      commentss = CommentModel.objects.all()

      return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'article_details': article_details,
                                                'comment_form': comment_form, 'comments': commentss,
                                                })



def tags_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Articles.objects.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)  # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'news/list.html', {'page': page,
                                              'posts': posts,
                                              'tag': tag})
```

post.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{article_details.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{article_details.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{article_details.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

    <p class="post-meta">
        Tags:
            <a href=""> {{ tag.name }}</a> |
    </p>



<div class="container"  id="Ratings">
    <a id="RatingImg" href=" like {{ article.pk }}">
        <img  src="{% static 'MainPage/image/Like.png' %}" >
                <h3> {{ article_details.article_like }} </h3>

    </a>


    <a id="RatingImg" href=" dislike {{ article.pk }}">
        <img  src="{% static 'MainPage/image/Dislike.png' %}" >
                <h3> {{ article_details.article_dislike }} </h3>

    </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

post.html

```
{% for tag in article_details.tags.all %}
    <a href="{% url  'post_tags_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
        {{ tag.name }}
    </a>
    {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```